# Koszul complex of a $\mathcal{D}$-module

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, d-modules

I am trying to understand the construction of push forward in the derived category of $\mathcal{D}$-modules using the Koszul complex. My question will be about the latter notion.

Let $X$ be a smooth algebraic variety over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $\mathcal{D}_X$ be the sheaf of algebraic differential operators. Let $dR(\mathcal{D}_X)$ be the de Rham complex of $\mathcal{D}_X$ considered as a left $\mathcal{D}_X$-module. For a right $\mathcal{D}_X$-module $M$ consider its Koszul complex
$$Kos(M):=M\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}dR(\mathcal{D}_X)\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}K_X^{-1},$$
where $\mathcal{O}_X$ is the sheaf of regular functions, $K_X$ is the sheaf of top degree forms.

**Questions.** (1) What is the differential in $Kos(M)$?

(2) What are the structures on $Kos(M)$ and how they are compatible with the differential? In particular is $Kos(M)$ a complex of right $\mathcal{D}_X$-modules with the differential commuting with this structure?

Is there a good place to read about it?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're trying to get at, this is not quite the correct thing. The correct "Koszul" complex (as you're calling it) is the complex
$$\begin{aligned}
(\operatorname{DR}_{X/pt}(M))^k
&:=\begin{cases}
\Omega^{n+k}_{X/\Bbb C}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}M, &\text{if }-n\leq k \leq 0,\\
0, &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}\\
d(\omega\otimes s) &= d\omega\otimes s + \sum_{i=1}^n (dz_i\wedge \omega)\otimes \partial_is,
\end{aligned}$$
where $\{z_i,\partial_i\}_{1\leq i\leq n}$ is a local coordinate system of $X$. This complex is *not* a $D_X$-module of any sort! Its hypercohomology $R\Gamma(X, \operatorname{DR}_{X/pt}(M))$ is the $D$-module direct image of $M$ via the map to a point. This hypercohomology is a complex of vector spaces, and it doesn't have any additional structure.

You can read more about this starting on page 45 of *D-Modules, Perverse Sheaves, and Representation Theory* by Hotta, Takeuchi, and Tanasaki (HTT).

**Edit**

I didn't notice at first that your $M$ is a right $D_X$-module. Anyway, the complex that you call $dR(\mathcal{D}_X)\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X} K_X^{-1}$ is (isomorphic to) what is usually called the Spencer complex, and it is an explicit $\mathcal{D}_X$-module resolution of the left $\mathcal{D}_X$-module $\mathcal{O}_X$. See Lemma 1.5.27 of HTT. It's common (though not universal) to denote this complex by $\operatorname{Sp}^\bullet_X$. Explicitly, if $\Theta_X$ denotes the tangent sheaf of $X$, then
$$\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{Sp}^{-k}_X
&:=\mathcal{D}_X\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}\mathsf{\Lambda}^{k}\Theta_X\\
d(P\otimes \partial_{i_1}\wedge\cdots \wedge \partial_{i_k}) &= \sum_j (-1)^{j+1} P\partial_{i_j}\otimes \partial_{i_1}\wedge\cdots \wedge\widehat{\partial_{i_j}}\wedge\cdots\wedge \partial_{i_k},
\end{aligned}$$
where $\{z_i,\partial_i\}_{1\leq i\leq n}$ is a local coordinate system of $X$. Then
$$\begin{aligned}
M\otimes_{\mathcal{D}_X}\operatorname{Sp}^{-k}_X
&\cong M\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}\mathsf{\Lambda}^{k}\Theta_X\\
d(s\otimes \partial_{i_1}\wedge\cdots \wedge \partial_{i_k}) &= \sum_j (-1)^{j+1} s\partial_{i_j}\otimes \partial_{i_1}\wedge\cdots \wedge\widehat{\partial_{i_j}}\wedge\cdots\wedge \partial_{i_k}.
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: What  you wrote is the de Rham complex of $M$.  This is not the same as the Koszul complex.

Comment: @makt Then I'm not sure what you mean by the Koszul complex of a D-module. Can you point me to where you found it?

Comment: See p.48 in these lecture notes https://people.math.harvard.edu/~gaitsgde/grad_2009/Dmod_brav.pdf

Comment: @makt Aha! What those lecture notes call $Kos(D_X)$ is isomorphic to what is usually called the Spencer complex. I've added some stuff to my answer to address this. Hopefully it's what you needed!

Comment: Thanks.  I am wondering what is $\wedge^{-k} \Theta_X$. In other words why the exterior power is negative.

Comment: @makt its so that the complex is in negative cohomological degrees. i realized i made a typo there though. it should be fixed now.

Comment: I think that this Spencer complex is not what is needed since apparently it does not have $\mathcal{D}_X$-module structure. The latter is necessary to construct pushforward: it should be tensored with $\mathcal{D}_{X\to Y}$ over $\mathcal{D}_X$.

Comment: @makt You are correct, it doesn't have a D-module structure. Instead, if $f\colon X\to Y$ is smooth, you can do the same construction with $\Theta_{X/Y}$, instead of $\Theta_X$, by which I mean the sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_Y$-linear derivations of $\mathcal{O}_X$, or equivalently (because $f$ is smooth) the $\mathcal{O}_X$-dual of $\Omega^1_{X/Y}$. This complex turns out to be quasi-isomorphic to $M\otimes_{\mathcal{D}_X} \mathcal{D}_{X\to Y}$.